# "oil" VS "oils"

Tags: singular-vs-plural, countability

1. Today’s hair care products, typically shampoos, usually incorporate  **natural oil** for better smoothness.
2. Today’s hair care products, typically shampoos, usually incorporate  **natural oils** for better smoothness.

What's the proper form of oil, singular or plural? I need some explanation for this specific case.

Comment: The above-mentioned question is similar to mine, but not exactly equal to mine. Could you tell me the correct choice here. Many many thanks,

Comment: Both are perfectly "correct". Arguably using the plural form carries a ***slightly*** stronger implication that some or all *specific* products contain multiple different types of "natural oil", but in general, that sense could either apply or not, with *either* form. But for reasons that aren't clear to me, marketing men nearly always prefer to use ***oils***.

Answer (score 1):

The link provided by Stangdon correctly answers your question. Oil is an uncountable (or mass) noun and is usually only spoken of in the singular. Some uncountable nouns can take a plural 's' under very specific conditions [(Plural Uncountable Nouns)](https://www.englishgrammar.org/plural-uncountable-nouns-2/), and oil is one of them. However, this only happens if you are talking about different types of oil, not when you are talking about more of the same type of oil.

> If you have a container of car oil and add more car oil to it, you still only have a container of car oil. It does not matter how often you do this (assuming the container is big enough), you will still only have a container of car oil. It never becomes a container of car oils.
>
> However, if I have a bottle of olive oil, a bottle of avocado oil and a bottle of grape seed oil in my pantry, I can say that my pantry contains **oils** for cooking.

Your second example (i.e. natural oils) is similar. In fact you could have said:

> Today’s hair care products, typically shampoos, usually incorporate various different natural oils for better smoothness.